# Android users receive DF-DFERH-01 when trying to rate android game published by me

Tags: android, google-play

Recently, I published game to android market. Problem is that no one from players is able to rate game using play market form. They receive error (DF-DFERH-01 Error receiving data from server) after trying to submit rating. Most advices about this errors are to clear android market cache, reinstall market application, etc, but none of them works, as even new players, no matter what is their location or device is still continue receiving this error. I wrote to google support week ago, but still have no any answer. Really appreciate any suggestions on what to do.

Comment: can you share app link if possible?

Comment: here is link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.radle.unblock3d.remastered. Note that for now, game is only available in Azerbaijan, Belarus, Portugal and Pakistan

Comment: See this I successfully rated it 

https://prnt.sc/rirvde

Comment: Yes, problem was fixed by google support team